Did Russell had something like the notion of domain in the sense defined now by mathematics textbooks?
The expression ∀x(ϕx → ψx) is supposed to mean that, in Russell's parlance, ϕx → ψx is true "for all values of x". However, what are those values that Russell is referring to?
At some point in a now distant past, all mathematicians would have probably happily subscribed to the idea that if x is a number, then x² is positive or null. Russell himself would have said that "x is a number" implies "x ≥ 0" for all values of x. Yet, after mathematicians decided that it was acceptable to say that there is a number i such that i² = -1, the expression ∀x("x is a number" → x ≥ 0) is no longer true.
I suppose that this sort of problem is solved by the notion of domain, whereby one can specify in advance that x belongs to some restrictive set of values, for example, in this case, ℕ. If the domain is ℕ, then "x is a number" implies "x ≥ 0" for all values of x if only because for all values of x now means "for all values of x in the domain", which means in this case x ∈ ℕ.
Thank you to correct me if I am wrong there.
Still, I couldn't find where Russell would have introduced the notion of domain as it is now defined in all mathematics textbooks. So, my question is:

Did Russell had something like the notion of domain in the sense defined now by mathematics textbooks?

Thank you for any scholarly references.

Eventually, forall n in N, P is just short-hand for forall n, n in N -> P.  Namely, quantification in the underlying language (e.g. FOL) is not restricted: quantified variables simply range over all possible individuals (individual constants).

Russell in 1903 (page 97) used domain of a relation in the modern sense: "It is to be held that to have a given relation to a given term is a predicate, so that all terms having this relation to this term form a class. It is to be held further that to have a given relation at all is a predicate, so that all referents with respect to a given relation form a class. It follows, by considering
the converse relation, that all relata also form a class. These two classes I shall call respectively the domain and the converse domain of the relation." But I suppose that this is not what you need...

@MauroALLEGRANZA That's it! Thanks. At least we can count on BR to explain himself.

@Julio Di Egidio "for all n in N, P is just short-hand for for all n, n in N -> P." Sure. - 2. "quantified variables simply range over all possible individuals (individual constants)" Well, that doesn't tell us what exactly are all those possible individuals.

"that doesn't tell us what exactly are all those possible individuals": sure it does, it's in the definition of the language itself, just a formal notion as such.  See e.g. here: [Predicate (mathematical logic)

WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic))


When I was learning programming, we had to document the algorithm we used and the domain and range of it overall. It's about the only math that seemed relevant to programming.

@JulioDiEgidio "ure it does, it's in the definition of the language itself, just a formal notion as such." Ok, so, take ∀x((Fx ∧ Gx) → (Fx ∨ Gx)). I suppose you agree it is true, which in fact just means that (Fx ∧ Gx) → (Fx ∨ Gx) is true for all values of x. What are all those values exactly? x = 10? x = Father Christmas? x = Everything? What?

We can see Rusell's Theory of Types sketched into Appendix B of Principles (1903) and fully described in Mathematical Logic as Based on the Theory of Types (1908).
See III. The Meaning and Range of Generalized Propositions, page 233:

"all men are mortal " will mean " if x is a man, x is mortal, where x may have any value within a certain range." "Hence the values of x must be somehow restricted within some legitimate totality. This seems to lead us to the traditional doctrine of a "universe of discourse" within which x must be supposed to lie. [...] it follows that the function "if x is a man, x is mortal" must have a certain range of significance".


Thanks, excellent!
